# Tabulator: how to modify local array when deleting rows?

Tags: javascript, dom, html-table, tabulator

I'm trying to build an interactive table that could be modified by the user. In my case, the original dataset is a local array of objects.

Tabulator has the buttonCross option to delete rows, but it only affects the table visuals. How can I make it find the matching object the row presents and delete it from the tabledata array?

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
let tabledata = [{
    animal: "hippo",
    color: "grey"
  },

{
    animal: "puma",
    color: "black"
  },
{
    animal: "flamingo",
    color: "pink"
  }

];

let table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  data: tabledata,
  layout: "fitDataFill",
  addRowPos: "bottom",
  reactiveData: true,
  headerSort: false,

  columns: [ //define the table columns
    {
      title: "animal",
      field: "animal",
      editor: "input"
    },
    {
      title: "color",
      field: "color",
      editor: "input"
    },
    {
      formatter: "buttonCross",
      width: 40,
      align: "center",
      cellClick: function (e, cell) {
        cell.getRow().delete();
      }
    },

  ],
});
```

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/anzuj/pen/abzRejp).
Would really appreciate some tips on how to make this work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working example for tabulator](https://codepen.io/arvindmaurya37/pen/abzQoJE?editors=1010)

the `filter` function is used to remove the current item for the collection
filter [Filter API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

First filter the object you don't need and then assign it to `tabledata`.

```
 cellClick: function (e, cell) {
        debugger;
        var animalToDelete={ animal:cell.getRow().getData().animal,
               color:cell.getRow().getData().color
              };
        var filtered=tabledata.filter(function(x){
          debugger;
          return x.animal!=animalToDelete.animal 
              && x.color!=animalToDelete.color;
        });
        tabledata=filtered;
        cell.getRow().delete();
      }
```

Comment: Works perfectly and I learned a lot trying to dissect WHY it works. Thank you ever so much for taking the time to help me with this!

Comment: It should be noted that this won't work as expected in case rows with identical data exist, as the filter method will delete the identical rows as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look to use tabulator in [Reactive Data Mode](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/reactivity#reactive-data)

In this mode it will update the table in real time to match the provided data array as it is changed, and vice versa it will update the array to match the table.

To do this set the ***reactiveData*** property to ***true*** in the tables constructor object.

```
//create table and assign data
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    reactiveData:true, //enable reactive data
    data:tableData, //assign data array
    columns:[
          {title:"Name", field:"name"},
          {title:"Age", field:"age", align:"left", formatter:"progress"},
          {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
          {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", align:"center"},
    ]
});
```

It will then maintain a link with the initial data source

Comment: If you look at my source code, reactiveData was set true, but the original data array was unchanged unfortunately. Which is why I came here to ask how it could be done. Perhaps it's unwanted behaviour and a bug?